# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int when trying to use dynamic Sql

Tags: sql, date, casting

I have created a sql statement which uses variables for the start and end dates and this works

```
  declare @startDate varchar(20) = '2022-06-01'
  declare @endDate varchar(20) = '2022-06-29'

  select distinct instanceId as [JourneyID], 
  CAST((select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) as varchar) as [AuditDate]
  ,CAST((select case when ISDATE(UpdateDate) = 1 THEN CAST(UpdateDate as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 176537 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId) as varchar) as [UpdatedDate]
  from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] qanda
  where (select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) >= CAST(@startDate as date)
  and (select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) <= CAST(@endDate as date)
  and UpdateDate is not null
```

I am trying to run this using dynamic SQL as I need to pass in server and database name dynamically as this query is used from an SSRS report.

I get a Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int

This is my dynamic SQL

```
@startDate varchar(15),
@endDate varchar(15),

set @OPENQUERY = 'Select [JourneyID], [AuditDate], [UpdatedDate] from OPENQUERY(' + @ServerName + ','''
set @sql = 'Select distinct instanceId as [JourneyID], 
  CAST((select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) as varchar) as [AuditDate]
  ,CAST((select case when ISDATE(UpdateDate) = 1 THEN CAST(UpdateDate as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 176537 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId) as varchar) as [UpdatedDate]
from ' + @DatabaseName + '.dbo.AB_SurveyQandA qanda where 
(select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) >= ' + CAST(@startDate as nvarchar) + '
  and (select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) <= ' + CAST(@endDate as nvarchar) +
' and UpdateDate is not null 
'')'
```

I have tried casting @startDate and @endDate as date but then it says date is incompatible with operand +

What do I need to do to be able to get this to work in a dynamic SQL string?

Answer (score 0):

As Per Ed Bangga suggestion here is the result of the SQL print
here is the result of the print SQL

```
Select [JourneyID], [AuditDate], [UpdatedDate] from OPENQUERY(MYSTERYDB,'Select distinct instanceId as [JourneyID], 
  CAST((select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) as varchar) as [AuditDate]
  ,CAST((select case when ISDATE(UpdateDate) = 1 THEN CAST(UpdateDate as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 176537 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId) as varchar) as [UpdatedDate]
from AbellioWMTData_April_21.dbo.AB_SurveyQandA qanda where 
(select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) >= '2022-06-01'
  and (select case when ISDATE(questionComment) = 1 THEN CAST(questionComment as date) END from [AbellioWMTData_April_21].[dbo].[AB_SurveyQandA] where protoQuestionId = 170346 and instanceId = qanda.instanceId ) <= '2022-06-29'
 and UpdateDate is not null 
')
```